# Will compiling python files to cython speed up the program?

Tags: python, cython

Will I see improvement in speed if I compile my python files to cython? Or do I need to rewrite my code in cython to actually see the improvement?

I'm doing like this below.

```
python convert_to_cython.py build_ext --inplace
```

Comment: To get the best improvement with `cython` you need to read the `cython` docs.  There have been a number of questions and answers about getting expected improvements with cython.  Study those.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what your example is supposed to be doing. What is `convert_to_cython.py`? It looks like you are confusing the [`setup.py` file for a distutils extension](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html) for your actual Python source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although this question is quite broad but in general terms **YES**. It does speed up your code and sometime in the order of 100.

For reference, the *Cython* docs says and I quote

> However, for performance critical code, it is often helpful to add static type declarations, as they will allow Cython to step out of the dynamic nature of the Python code and generate simpler and faster C code - sometimes faster **by orders of magnitude**

The main reason why languages like C/C++ are faster is that they create machine-dependent assembly language to tweak all the optimization which are hardware dependent. This is achieved using compilers mostly because few things like

1. statically typed variable
2. loop unrolling
3. Branch prediction

etc..

Now One of the important feature *Statically typed variable* is extensively used by Cython. As python variables are typeless and C variables are not, Cython can give users flexibility to statically fix the type of their variables.

In Cython doc [website](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) they showed how just by mentioning the type actually produced **35%** faster performance.

**Note** *However my final word is that you be careful while converting your Python code in Cython because you may be using some frameworks/APIs in your project which doesn't have support for Cython. Sometime even if you convert your code into Cython, that hardly changes anything inside. So it all depends on your code.*

**Hence first make sure of complete portability of your Python code in Cython and also check if that is absolutely necessary.**

**Edit 1** One more thing is that converting you code in Cython, makes it less readable so please be mindful of that.

Again Quoting from Cython Docs

> It must be noted, however, that type declarations can make the source code more verbose and thus less readable. It is therefore discouraged to use them without good reason, such as where benchmarks prove that they really make the code substantially faster in a performance critical section

**Edit 2** Answering for the question *Or do I need to rewrite my code in cython to actually see the improvement?*

**No** because the Cython compiler does the whole thing for you.

> The Cython compiler will convert it into C code which makes equivalent calls to the Python/C API.
>
> As Cython can accept almost any valid python source file, one of the hardest things in getting started is just figuring out how to compile your extension.

For more info visit [**this**](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html)

Comment: The first quote contradicts your answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The first quote says that by statically mentioning the type, it creates faster executable, and I mentioned the same in my answer too. So how am I contradicting ??

Comment: "Or do I need to rewrite my code in cython to actually see the improvement?" Adding static declarations is rewriting part of it.

Answer (score 4):

As it stands, this question is much too broad because the answer depends greatly on what your Python code looks like. Without seeing it, or at least having some idea of what it does, it's not possible to give you a straightforward answer.

If your code mainly calls functions from other compiled libraries then you may well see no improvement, or even slower runtimes. For example, there are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7799977/1461210) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30738820/1461210) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5331275/1461210) on SO from people who can't understand why Cython doesn't magically speed up their numpy code. However, things like nested Python `for` loops can be very good candidates for speeding up using Cython.

Your first step should always be to **profile** your code (e.g. using the excellent [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/)). Once you've identified where the bottlenecks are then you can think about how to speed them up, possibly by rewriting them in Cython. It will almost certainly be a waste of time for you to go and rewrite all of your existing Python code in Cython.